# How to pass a path as argument to shell script and copy a file from the path

Tags: shell, directory, arguments, filenames, any

I've written bash script to open a file passed as argument and write it into another file.
But my script will work properly only if the file is in the current directory. Now i need to open and write the file that is not in the current directory also.

If compile is the name of my script, then ./compile next/123/file.txt should open the file.txt in the passed path. How can I do it?

```
#!/bin/sh
#FIRST SCRIPT
clear
echo "-----STARTING COMPILATION-----"
#echo $1
name=$1   # Copy the filename to name
find . -iname $name -maxdepth 1 -exec cp {} $name \;
new_file="tempwithfile.adb"
cp $name $new_file #copy the file to new_file

echo "compiling"
dir >filelist.txt
gcc writefile.c
run_file="run_file.txt"
echo $name > $run_file
./a.out
echo ""
echo "cleaning"
echo ""

make clean
make -f makefile
./semantizer -da <withfile.adb
```

Thankyou

Comment: Can you add here as well what exactly you are doing in your script?

Comment: I am trying to open the file that is passed as argument and write it into another file.but currently its working only if the passed file is present in the current directory.

Comment: I have included the code used. Someone please help.

Comment: Here the problem is that you use `find` command and you are providing the search path as `.` which means that find will search from current directory. Obviously if your passed file name in the input as argument containing also path part the find command will not find anything.