# Passing a path as an argument to a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, directory, arguments

I've written bash script to open a file passed as an argument and write it into another file. But my script will work properly only if the file is in the current directory. Now I need to open and write the file that is not in the current directory also.

If compile is the name of my script, then `./compile next/123/file.txt` should open the `file.txt` in the passed path. How can I do it?

```
#!/bin/sh
#FIRST SCRIPT
clear
echo "-----STARTING COMPILATION-----"
#echo $1
name=$1   # Copy the filename to name
find . -iname $name -maxdepth 1 -exec cp {} $name \;
new_file="tempwithfile.adb"
cp $name $new_file #copy the file to new_file

echo "compiling"
dir >filelist.txt
gcc writefile.c
run_file="run_file.txt"
echo $name > $run_file
./a.out
echo ""
echo "cleaning"
echo ""

make clean
make -f makefile
./semantizer -da <withfile.adb
```

Comment: why do you have to find the file, if you already know it's path?

Comment: I am not trying to find the file. But to open it, if it exists, and write it into a file in the current directory. But as you can see in the code, I'm copying $1 to name and name to newfile. It is not working as I need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass a path as argument to shell script and copy a file from the path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24291992/how-to-pass-a-path-as-argument-to-shell-script-and-copy-a-file-from-the-path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code and your question are a bit messy and unclear.

It seems that you intended to `find` your file, given as a parameter to your script, but failed due to the `maxdepth`.

If you are given `next/123/file.txt` as an argument, your `find` gives you a warning:

> find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a
>   non-option argument -iname, but options are not positional (-maxdepth
>   affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after
>   it).  Please specify options before other arguments.

Also `-maxdepth` gives you the depth `find` will go to find your file until it quits. `next/123/file.txt` has a depth of `2` directories.

Also you are trying to copy the given file within `find`, but also copied it using `cp` afterwards.

As said, your code is really messy and I don't know what you are trying to do. I will gladly help, if you could elaborate :).

There are some questions that are open:

1. Why do you have to `find` the file, if you already know its path? Do you always have the whole path given as an argument? Or only part of the path? Only the `basename` ?
2. Do you simply want to copy a file to another location?
3. What does your `writefile.c` do? Does it write the content of your file to another? `cp` does that already.

I also recommend using variables with CAPITALIZED letters and checking the exit status of used commands like `cp` and `find`, to check if these failed.

Anyway, here is my script that might help you:

```
#!/bin/sh
#FIRST SCRIPT
clear
echo "-----STARTING COMPILATION-----"
echo "FILE: $1"
[ $# -ne 1 ] && echo "Usage: $0 <file>" 1>&2 && exit 1

FILE="$1"   # Copy the filename to name
FILE_NEW="tempwithfile.adb"
cp "$FILE" "$FILE_NEW" # Copy the file to new_file
[ $? -ne 0 ] && exit 2

echo
echo "----[ COMPILING ]----"
echo
dir &> filelist.txt # list directory contents and write to filelist.txt
gcc writefile.c # ???

FILE_RUN="run_file.txt"
echo "$FILE" > "$FILE_RUN"

./a.out

echo
echo "----[ CLEANING ]----"
echo

make clean
make -f makefile
./semantizer -da < withfile.adb
```

Comment: :Thank You. I'll explain my need. Currently what I do is, I execute ./compile a.adb from terminal. a.adb can contain many other files refered from it. All these files need to be in the current directory presently. writefile.c writes all these files into a single file. I have used 'find -iname' to overcome the problem of case sensitivity in case of filename. For eg, directory may contain A.adb instead of a.adb.

Comment: so you are given only the filename of your `*.adb` file, then you want to find it in subdirectories, copy it to the current directory. Your `writefile.c` will collect the referenced files in your `*.adb` file and write them into a single file. All you need now, is `find` to actually find your given adb file, am I right?

Comment: If I give './compile ../previous/file.txt', will it go to the file.txt in the parent directory??

Comment: Well yeah my script above does that, but why do you have to find the file, if you already know its path `../previous/file.txt`?

Comment: Absolutely. If any path is given,either forward or backward , the file should be found. Also all referenced files will be in that directory and not in the current directory.

Comment: Because fronm writefile.c, I need to access those files in some other directory that is not the current directory. How will I do that. Currently what I'm doing is, when *.adb is refered, I'll  check if it is in filelist.txt. If so I'll open and write it. Now if the file is in other directory I need to modify my filelist.txt also na?

Comment: You can pass the compiled executable of writefile.c the filename as a parameter, like `./a.out "$FILE"` and access it in your writefile.c.

Comment: Sorry.. I didn't get it. Passing with exe??? How to access it once it is compiled?